# Qual a origem da expressão "Chamada para Tóquio"?

Tags: origem-histórica

A informação na net é difusa, e [neste posto](http://ojaimeexplica.blogspot.com/2009/06/explicacao-n-3-chamada-para-toquio.html) faz-se referência a uma alegado tratado de amizade entre o Japão e o Brasil em 1895 onde teria havido muita emigração do Japão para o Brasil, e em que haveria uma confusão fonética entre "falar à grande" e "falar à glande".

> Recuemos a 5 de Novembro de 1895, mais concretamente, à assinatura do
>   Tratado de Amizade e Comércio Japão-Brasil,em Paris, estabelecendo as
>   relações diplomáticas entre os dois países. Este acordo permitiu a
>   emigração de muitos japoneses vindos de um Japão superpovoado e
>   isolado do Mundo. A política emigratória tinha, assim, como principal
>   objetivo aliviar as tensões sociais devido à escassez de terras
>   cultiváveis e endividamento dos trabalhadores rurais, permitindo assim
>   a implementação de projetos de modernização. Do outro lado, estava o
>   Brasil, que tinha falta de mão-de-obra para as plantações de café. Mas
>   não foi fácil a adaptação destes japoneses a este belo país. Idioma,
>   clima, estilo de vida, hábitos alimentares... tudo isto era
>   diferente... e aumentavam as saudades de casa... e dos seus mais
>   próximos. Aproveitando esse sentimento nostálgico e saudoso reinante
>   nesse nicho de mercado, a operadora estatal brasileira apresentou, já
>   na década de 60 do século passado, uma campanha com preços nunca antes
>   vistos. Rejubilaram, assim, todos os nipónicos e espalharam a notícia
>   entre todos, já num português algo asiático, da seguinte forma: "Com
>   estes pleços, já podemos falal à glande". Bom, dito isto, os adeptos
>   do sexo oral não desperdiçaram tempo, vendo numa "chamada para Tóquio"
>   algo dirigido à glande. E, sabe-se bem que, para estes, não há melhor
>   forma de alguém se dirigir à glande que sob a forma de um belo
>   felátio! Como tal, meus amigos, quando se fala em "Chamada para
>   Tóquio" falamos, pois, num felátio.

Mas não se citam quaisquer fontes. Portanto reitero a pergunta: Qual a origem da expressão "Chamada para Tóquio"?

Comment: Bem, eu devo ser muito ignorante ou despassarado, mas não fazia a mínima do que era uma chamada para Tóquio, e só fiquei a saber quando cheguei ao fim da tua citação. Não sei se haverá muitos mais como eu. Se houver, não se perdia explicares logo à cabeça.

Comment: @Jacinto ver, a título de exemplo, [este programa](https://tviplayer.iol.pt/programa/governo-sombra/53c6b3a33004dc006243d5fb/video/5d2996ae0cf25a69cc4a5ecc) do governo sombra, no tempo `1:06:09`

Comment: João, eu fiquei convencido logo à primeira que *chamada para Tóquio* tinha esse significado. Estava só a sugerir que talvez fosse útil indicar o significado logo à cabeça.

Comment: Essa expressão praticamente não se encontra em sites brasileiros; parece ser só portuguesa. O Priberam concorda. Isto deita por terra a explicação do "falar à glande" entre os japoneses no Brasil. Mas a origem continua obscura. Será uma variante de *chamada para Bruxelas?* Eu não conhecia esta, mas até se compreende.